# How to loop through .txt file

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I need help reading in a .txt file one line at a time. This is the text file for winning Powerball numbers:

```
Draw Date   WB1 WB2 WB3 WB4 WB5 PB  PP
08/27/2016  48  32  63  04  49  20  2
08/24/2016  25  11  09  65  64  16  3
```

I would like to read in one line at a time. The closest I got was:

```
<cfloop file="http://www.powerball.com/powerball/winnums-text.txt" index="chars" characters="23">
  <cfoutput>#chars#</cfoutput>
  <br>
</cfloop>
```

The output was this:

```
Draw Date WB1 WB2 WB3
WB4 WB5 PB PP 08/27/
2016 48 32 63 04 4
```

This make each 23 characters a line, which is incorrect.  Also, I don't know how to get rid of the header.

```
Draw Date WB1 WB2 WB3 WB4 WB5 PB PP
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need something to identify you're on the first row to not output it. Also, drop the `characters="23"` so the loop is based on a line breaks within the file.

```
<cfset outputRow = false>
<cfoutput>
  <cfloop file="http://www.powerball.com/powerball/winnums-text.txt" index="chars">
    <cfif outputRow>      
      #chars#<br>
    <cfelse>
      <cfset outputRow = true>
    </cfif>
  </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: True, but the output is still skewed. May want to drop the `characters="23"`. Not sure they really wanted to read 23 characters at a time anyway ;-)

Comment: Thank you Matt and Leigh. It worked after I dropped the "characters="23"". But I don't understand how? How did it know each row. "23" was how many character in each row. And I though that's how it read row to row

Comment: @Thomas when it's a file each iteration in the loop is based on a line break

Comment: Thanks Matt. So the line breaks where apart of the file.

Comment: @Thomas - Yep.  If you examine the ascii values of each character, you will see each line ends with a new line character, ie `chr(10)`. RE: *"23" was how many character in each row* FWIW, there are actually 37 total (including spaces). The `characters` attribute includes everything, so if you really did want to use it, you would have to use characters=37 for this file.